# Result from division with INT in Postgres other then MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, division

I have a problem. If artikel.preis is 2430 and umsatz.opreis is 2722.

```
COALESCE(ROUND(artikel.preis/NULLIF(umsatz.opreis,0),0),9999) as kontroll
```

In MySQL i get 1 as result but in PostgresSQL i get 0.

Why is it like that? 2430/2722 = 0.8927 and should be rounded to 1.

How can i get this to work in Postgres and what is other in postgres then in MySQL?

Comment: This looks dangerously like you are creating a divide by ZERO condition if umsatz.opreis is NULL

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL, the / operator does the division based on the types of its operands, if both `artikel.preis` and `umsatz.opreis` are integers the division will be an integer division:

```
select 2430/2722
```

will return 0, while

```
select 2430::float/2722::float
```

will return the expected result. Try with this:

```
COALESCE(ROUND(artikel.preis::float/NULLIF(umsatz.opreis::float,0),0),9999) as kontroll
```

however, be careful about `umsatz.opreis` being null or being zero, it will result in a divide by zero condition. If you have problems with round this query will convert the result back to integer:

```
COALESCE((artikel.preis::float/umsatz.opreis::float)::int,9999) as kontroll
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now it stand round funktion doesnt exist. if i take that away i get 0.8927.. but i need to round the answer as a INT

Comment: @user2210516 which version of postgresql do you have? please see my updated answer