# Preventing integer division by casting one of the operands as non-integer

Tags: postgresql, casting, integer-division

Do I have to cast **both** the numerator and the denominator to a non-integer data type to prevent integer division?

Comment: Honestly how hard would that have been to test? `select  1/2::numeric ; 0.50000000000000000000`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It is *very* easy to test. All the more surprising is that some upvoted answers that I listed under **"SEE ALSO"** section have one extra cast (e.g., 2 casts, when 1 cast is enough). This extra cast is confusing and not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to cast **one** of the operands (*either* the numerator or the denominator) to prevent integer division, as the manual says. **Casting *both* is not necessary:**

```
select 2 / 4;                      -- 0
select 2::numeric / 4;             -- 0.50000000000000000000
select 2 / 4::numeric;             -- 0.50000000000000000000
select 2::numeric / 4::numeric;    -- 0.50000000000000000000
```

**SEE ALSO:**

- [PostgreSQL manual: Numeric Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)
- [PostgreSQL manual: Mathematical Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)
- [PostgreSQL: When casting an integer to a non-integer type to force floating point division in PostgreSQL, which number type should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55537600/967621)

**These have 2 casts, while only 1 cast is needed:**

- [How to divide COUNT(CASE ) by COUNT()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71737895/967621)
- [Result from division with INT in Postgres other then MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34616262/967621)